# If you cancel/dispose DisposableSubscriber, onComplete event is not called

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

Using this code:

```
        Disposable d =
            Flowable.range(1, 5)
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSubscriber<Integer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onStart() {
                            request(1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNext(Integer t) {
                            if (t == 3) {
                                cancel();
                            }
                            System.out.println(t);
                            request(1);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {
                            t.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            System.out.println("Done!");
                        }

                    });
```

will print

```
1
2
3
```

If you cancel/dispose a subscription, `onComplete` is never called, neither is `onError`. Is this the correct behavior?

Is there an event called `onDispose()` or some way to know where the subscription is disposed ?

Comment: Are you talking about `doOnDispose()`?

Comment: It is the correct behavior. Cancellation ends the lifecycle so no further events should be expected. However, since you manually cancel the flow, you can do whatever you'd have done in `onComplete` right there too.